# Java exception when trying to run query in SQuirreL

Tags: java, sql, ioexception, squirrel-sql

I've installed `SQuirreL 3.5.3` and I'm using `Java 1.7.0_67 (JRE)`. This is at the end of my PATH environment variable: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"`.

I've set up drivers and an alias and am able to connect to my database.

My problem is that when I run any query (e.g. "select sysdate"), I'm getting a "Request not handled" exception. Any idea what's causing this?

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Request not handled
    at org.iws.jdbc.server.JDBCServlet.doPost(JDBCServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0
```

Comment: Is your SQL statement *literally* `select sysdate`?  What DBMS are you using?  (Even Oracle, which is what I found with sysdate when I Googled, requires you to use the pseudo-table `dual`.)

Comment: I'm confused. You claim you are using SQuirrel, but the stacktrace shows that you are using some kind of web application to run the statement. I'm pretty sure that you won't get a stacktrace that contains `org.apache.coyote.http11.` from an error in SQuirrel.

Comment: @Makoto The DBMS is Vertica. Yes, literally select sysdate. It works for others near me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, my claim is true. The stacktrace comes from an error in SQuirreL.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver my colleagues had given me was out of date. Got the new driver and queries are now working.